# Taking too much time to copy from one excel sheet row (matching rows) to another excel sheet - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this code for command click event to copy rows from one sheet with some criteria to another sheet. It is taking too much time to get loaded into the sheet.

Is there a way to speed this up? I am new to VBA excel and I am learning.

```
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim strValue As String
Dim lngRowOutput As Long

' getting last row of Material Master data
lngLastRow = Sheets(2).UsedRange.Rows.Count
' MsgBox lngLastRow

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Clear down sheet from Row 2. Row 1 is for column headers.

Sheets(6).Range("2:1048570").Clear  'MM Criticality sheet

lngRowOutput = 2 ' where are we going to write the values to in Sheet2  

For lngRow = 2 To lngLastRow
     strValue = Sheets(2).Cells(lngRow, 5).Value  ' getting value from column D

    'Checking for particular text in the transactions..
    If InStr(1, strValue, "specified in the table ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
         Sheets(2).Rows(lngRow).Copy
        Sheets(6).Rows(lngRowOutput).PasteSpecial
        lngRowOutput = lngRowOutput + 1
    Else
  '    MsgBox Sheets(3).Rows(lngRow).Copy
    End If

Next lngRow

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Worksheets(6).Activate
Worksheets(6).Visible = True
Worksheets(6).Select
End sub
```

Comment: Jen, code should be indented 4 spaces in a question.

Answer (score 0):

Try the simple change below. Instead of copy paste, reference the values specifically:

```
Dim lngLastRow As Long Dim lngRow As Long Dim strValue As String Dim lngRowOutput As Long

' getting last row of Material Master data
lngLastRow = Sheets(2).UsedRange.Rows.Count
' MsgBox lngLastRow

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Clear down sheet from Row 2. Row 1 is for column headers.


Sheets(6).Range("2:1048570").Clear  'MM Criticality sheet

lngRowOutput = 2 ' where are we going to write the values to in Sheet2  


For lngRow = 2 To lngLastRow
     strValue = Sheets(2).Cells(lngRow, 5).Value  ' getting value from column D

    'Checking for particular text in the transactions..
    If InStr(1, strValue, "specified in the table ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Sheets(6).Rows(lngRowOutput) = Sheets(2).Rows(lngRow).Value
        lngRowOutput = lngRowOutput + 1
    Else
  '    MsgBox Sheets(3).Rows(lngRow).Copy
    End If

Next lngRow
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Worksheets(6).Activate 
Worksheets(6).Visible = True
Worksheets(6).Select 
End sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much Kyle. It is much faster now. Can you please explain what you did in the new line....Sheets(6).Rows(lngRowOutput) = Sheets(2).Rows(lngRow).Value

Comment: Instead of copying the value from `Sheet(2).Rows(lngRow)` and pasting in `Sheets(6).Rows(lngRowOutput)`, I directly assign the value of `Sheet(2).Rows(lngRow)` to the range `Sheets(6).Rows(lngRowOutput)`. It is a much quicker operation than copy/paste. If this answer works for you, please accept my answer.