# Spare time when searching rows between worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I've written some code that takes too much time to calculate.

It "brushes" rows in a specific column, from a worksheet (Plan1, with 11,617 rows, start data at 2nd row), looks for the cell's value, stores this value, searches every row in a specific column in a second worksheet (Plan2, with 158,715 rows, start data at 2nd row too) and verify if the encountered value matches the searched value. If true, the value is stored, and then assigned to an unused cell in previous worksheet (Plan1), in the same row but in new column. It works, but as the number of rows are enormous, it takes around 1 hour to fulfill each column in Plan1.

Once, I tried to use VLOOKUP, that takes very less time (around 5min), but the data were oddly corrupted, so I started to use VBA programming to have more data accuracy. I looked up at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108461/taking-too-much-time-to-copy-from-one-excel-sheet-row-matching-rows-to-another), but my issue is too much specific than the explanation of the answers. I translated the code for better understanding, so if you notice a syntax error, don't worry; this code was working before the translation.

Finally, here is my code.

```
Sub AddAddress()

    Dim Plan1, Plan2 As Worksheet
    Dim FirstRow As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim CurrentRow As Long
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long
    Dim SoughtId, EncounteredId, Address As String
    Dim SuccessCounter As Integer
    Dim StartTime, EndTime, ElapsedTime As Date

    StartTime = Time()

    Set Plan1 = Application.Worksheets("Plan1")
    Set Plan2 = Application.Worksheets("Plan2")

    'Define calculation mode
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    'Use Plan1
    With Plan1

        'Select this worksheet
        .Select

        'Memory optimization
        ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
        ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
        .DisplayPageBreaks = False

        'First and last rows' loop
        FirstRow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
        LastRow = .UsedRange.End(xlDown).Row

        'Loop execution
        For CurrentRow = LastRow To FirstRow Step -1

            'Check Id value in A column
            With .Cells(CurrentRow, "A")

                'Store SoughtId
                SoughtId = .Value

                'Search Address via Id on Plan2
                With Plan2

                    .Select
                    Dim ActiveCell As String

                    With .Range("D:D")

                        'Search Id
                        If (SoughtId = .Find(SoughtId)) Then

                            EncounteredId = SoughtId

                        End If

                        ActiveCell = .Find(SoughtId).Address

                    End With

                    'Define/store Address
                    With .Range(ActiveCell)

                        'Being in current column, go to the column that
                        'contains the wanted value if this value is not empty
                        If .Offset(0, 9).Value <> "" Then

                            Address = .Offset(0, 9).Value

                        End If

                    End With

                End With

                Plan1.Select

                'Append Address obtained value in corresponding row's cell
                'and increment SuccessCounter
                With .Offset(0, 15)

                    .Value = Address

                End With

            SuccessCounter = SuccessCounter + 1

            End With

        Next CurrentRow

    End With

    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With

    EndTime = Time()
    ElapsedTime = EndTime - StartTime

    MsgBox "Operation finished!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Added addresses: " & SuccessCounter & vbNewLine & "Time elapsed: " & ElapsedTime

End Sub
```

Comment: I wouldn't use Find() repeatedly on such a large sheet (Plan2), but instead use a Dictionary lookup.  See my example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265919/faster-find-method-and-filter-position-comparison/14268760#14268760

Comment: Does your data actually start in row 1 or are there column heading labels and the real data starts in row 2?

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm evaluating your answer right now and will give you a brief soon.

Comment: @Jeeped I edited the post to answer your questions

Answer (score 0):

I would try not switching back and forth between the two worksheets using the `.select` method. Instead try referencing those values on the worksheets directly without switching. It would looks something like `Worksheets("Plan1").Range("Range You Want")`. Also try to not use `ActiveCell` because that is causing excel to change which cell it has selected hundreds of thousands of times, which is slow.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your idea improved and cleaned a lot my code, but 3+hours has passed and it still doesn't finish... >< thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. You are correctly using `With ... End With` blocks but defeat their purpose by adding `.Select` commands within the blocks.
2. You `.Find` once to see if something exists and then `.Find` again to get a value
3. *ActiveCell*, *Address*, etc are reserved words and should not be redefined as variables.
4. Declarations like `Dim Plan1, Plan2 As Worksheet` create *Plan1* as a variant not a worksheet type.

See if this speeds things up a notch.

```
Sub Addaddr()
    Dim Plan1 As Worksheet, Plan2 As Worksheet
    Dim rw As Long, FirstRow As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim SoughtId, addr As String
    Dim SuccessCounter As Long
    Dim StartTime As Date, EndTime As Date, ElapsedTime As Date

    StartTime = Time()

    Set Plan1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Plan1")
    Set Plan2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Plan2")

    'Define calculation mode
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    With Plan1
        'First and last rows' loop
        FirstRow = 1
        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        For rw = LastRow To FirstRow Step -1

            'Store SoughtId
            SoughtId = .Cells(rw, "A").Value

            'Search addr via Id on Plan2
            addr = vbNullString
            With Plan2
                If CBool(Application.CountIf(.Range("D:D"), SoughtId)) Then
                    addr = .Cells(Application.Match(SoughtId, .Range("D:D"), 0), "M").Value
                End If
            End With
            If CBool(Len(addr)) Then
                .Cells(rw, "O") = addr
                SuccessCounter = SuccessCounter + 1
            End If

        Next rw

    End With

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    EndTime = Time()
    ElapsedTime = EndTime - StartTime

    MsgBox "Operation finished!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Added addres: " & SuccessCounter & vbNewLine & "Time elapsed: " & ElapsedTime

End Sub
```

I've used the worksheet [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countif-function-4764f197-0127-49fa-9f5a-b188177b6db4) to determine if a cross-reference value exists, then a [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) to retrieve the row number. This is not the most efficient but likely better than two `.Find` operations without error control.

As mentioned, this would really benefit from memory based processing like a dictionary or variant array. Take a look at the timed speed test [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29451126/error13-in-excel-vba-in-data-file).

Comment: I thank you a lot, as I can see you are experienced on VBA programming, your code is more clean and clear. But did not work for me. I adapted the lines 36 and 40 to get the `M` and `O` columns via a variable (eg. `addr = .Cells(Application.Match(SoughtId, .Range("D:D"), 0), myVariable).Value`, wherein `myVariable` is of `String` type and has `m` stored via `InputBox`). The result was an infinite loop. I did run the code for one column to be fulfilled with the information and I went to do someting else. Took about two hours, when I came back I saw the code running yet. :/

Comment: Another thing, the `.Select` command you told about is to be able to change the window view. The lines `ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View` and `ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView` right after the `.Select` command correspond to the Macro going back to the normal view for speed. I'd take part of the code from [here](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s4/win001.htm). Anyway, I changed the code another time right now, following your code improvings (like removing the `.Select` command) and adjusting what I need. It is still slow, but I guess there's no way to do it at this way without being slow...

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way for this still is using a formula with the built-in functions of Excel. I put this formula into column O of sheet "Plan1":

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH($A1;Plan2!$D:$D;0));"";OFFSET(Plan2!$D$1;MATCH($A1;Plan2!$D:$D;0)-1;9))
```

This is how it works:

`MATCH($A1;Plan2!$D:$D;0))`
returns a row number if the value in Plan1!$A1 is found in the range Plan2!$D:$D, or a #NV error if not.
If not found, the formula returns an empty string
If found, the value at that same row number but a column offset by 9 ("D" -> "M") is returned.

This does indeed work. I tested it with a Plan1 of length 600 and a Plan2 with length 15.0000. Recalculation on my PC takes around 1 second. The VBA sub given by Jeedped does take about the same time.

Of course, repeating the `MATCH()` function is costing us runtime. Better you put
`MATCH($A1;Plan2!$D:$D;0)`
into an unused, off-screen column (say, "X") and use
`=IF(ISERROR($X1);"";OFFSET(Plan2!$D$1;$X1-1;9))`
in the target column. (example formulas all go into row 1).

Comment: With 11K rows in the *Plan1* worksheet, I'd recommend using some form of non-volatile [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) in place of that [OFFSET function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592). Maybe something like `=IFERROR(INDEX('Plan2'!M:M, MATCH(A1, 'Plan2'!D:D, 0)), "")` in 'Plan1'!O:O.

Comment: I deliberately used the `OFFSET` function as the OP wants to compare Plan1!A values to Plan2!D values BUT retrieve Plan2!I values into Plan1!O. See original code.

Comment: I generally don't recommend 11K rows worth of any formula that recalculates whenever any value in the entire workbook changes but that is up to the OP. In any event, you might want to change the *cols* parameter of your offset. 6 columns to the right of column D would seem to be column J not column M. I believe the correct column offset is *9*.

Comment: You're absolutely right, on both accounts. Up to OP. I've corrected the offsets, thanks.

Comment: @user1016274 thank you, your formula did work for me, but retrieved only the first row's value referrenced, which is not useful for me as I need to fill the cells down to the last row with the formula (in other words, when I fill 'em down, the cells filled stay with the same value as the first). I need to verify if a cell's value in a column in `Plan1` match the cell's value encountered in `Plan 2`, then get a value relative to the cell's value encountered in `Plan2`, in the same row, and put it in the corresponding cell's value in `Plan1`, in same row but in another not used column (any).

Comment: @Jeeped sorry about my noobish question, but what do you mean when you say "11K rows"? Thanx

Comment: @user1016274 another thing, before I tried to use VBA, I used VLOOKUP formula, it worked almost perfectly, but the data, at some many rows, went oddly corrupted/incorrect. I guess it was because the high number of rows, so I started VBA programming. Thereby, how can I be sure that a formula can be really effective?

Comment: @M4Lk  -Your description of the problem seemed to indicate that you had slightly over 11,000 rows of data.